# Sending HTML file type input from HTML form to a given email address

Tags: html, node.js, forms, backend, form-submit

I have an HTML form on my website where the input type for some input fields is text/number whereas for other input fields the input type is file (the user will be uploading a file from their system, PDF to be more specific). I was wondering whether there is a way through which I can send this HTML form data to a specified email address (GMAIL to be more specific).

Below is a screenshot of the form that I have on my website which will provide you with some idea regarding the data that I want to send from HTML form to a specified email address:

[image]

It would be really great if someone could refer any tutorial here or mention a step by step instructions himself. Thanks!

**NOTE:** I found a few tutorials online where they have shared some techniques to send HTML form data to a specified email address but none of them dealt with sending HTML file type input to a given email address.

Comment: well you can use nodemailer library and upon sending the email you can attach the cv file with the email as well.